# Oracle - How do I create a table that has an autoincrementing unique key for the ID

Tags: sql, oracle

This is the first time that I've use oracle SQL and I'm having a problem creating tables with a unique key.

I don't understand why this auto-incrementing id is not working:

```
ID BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
```

The next question I have is why I am getting an error in each of my statements:

```
ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
```

Here is my code:

```
--
-- Sequence for aout incrment
--
CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS AUTO_INC_SEQ
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1;

--
-- Table Person
--
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS FITNESS_PERSON
(
ID NUMBER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
FIRST_NAME VARCHAR NOT NULL,
LAST_NAME VARCHAR NOT NULL,
NICK_NAME VARCHAR NOT NULL,
DATE_BIRTH DATE NOT NULL,
PASSWORD VARCHAR NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT UNIQUE(NICK_NAME)
);

--
-- Table BMR
--
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS FITNESS_BMR
(
ID NUMBER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
VALUE FLOAT NOT NULL,
VALUE_DATE DATE NOT NULL
);

--
-- M:N for BMR and Person
--
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS FITNESS_BMR_PERSON
(
BMR_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
PERSON_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY(BMR_ID) REFERENCES FITNESS_BMR(ID),
FOREIGN KEY(PERSON_ID) REFERENCES FITNESS_PERSON(ID),
CONSTRAINT BMR_PER PRIMARY KEY(BMR_ID, PERSON_ID)
);
```

What's the right way to do this (create a table and with an auto-incrementing key that is unique).

Comment: Oracle doesn't support `IF NOT EXISTS` for `CREATE TABLE` or `CREATE SEQUENCE`. It also doesn't have `AUTO_INCREMENT` columns. Remove those and you'll get a lot further. As for the `IF NOT EXISTS`, just put a `DROP TABLE whatever` before each `CREATE TABLE` - you'll get an error if the table doesn't already exist, but it's harmless.

Comment: If the table does exist and has data in it deleting it could hardly be described as harmless.

Comment: ok thx. that helped alot ^^
how do i solve my auto increment problem. because i want my id to get increment automatically by inserting new data.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant - good point; I wasn't treating this like a real production app, and that's sloppy. user1882812, please take note of what Michael says. If this was for a "real" app you'd never drop the tables in the create script, and you might as well start now treating every app as real. Instead, have a well-guarded rollback script for dropping tables. Also, in looking at your table relationships, any rollback script will have to drop `FITNESS_BMR_PERSON` *first* because of its foreign key relationships to `FITNESS_BMR` and `FITNESS_PERSON`.

Comment: There are plenty of examples on the web. One of them is [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/sequences.php). Check it out and it'll make sense after you try it. Good luck :)

Comment: ok thx.
one last question.

Comment: for the table person i get this error: ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis but i think i have everything ^^

Comment: user1882812, I have also posted an answer.  It took a while to write.  Please be sure to be patient on SO, it will help you :)

Comment: yeah thank you :) But the missing left parenthesis problem is there now ^^ i have two opening parenthesis and two closing. dont no why the system is complaining

Comment: Your "missing left parenthesis" is because of the `VARCHAR` column types. You have to supply a length, for example `VARCHAR(25)`.

Comment: and if i add these i get an "missing right parenthesis" error -.-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a table, a sequence to generate unique ID values and a trigger.

For example:

Table:

```
CREATE Table FITNESS_BMR
(
ID NUMBER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
VALUE FLOAT NOT NULL,
VALUE_DATE DATE NOT NULL
);
```

Sequence: `create sequence t1_seq start with 1 increment by 1 nomaxvalue;`

Trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER test_trigger
BEFORE INSERT
ON FITNESS_BMR
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SELECT t1_seq.nextval INTO :NEW.ID FROM dual;
END;
/
```

Comment: I haven't used Oracle in 10 years so you might have to fine-tune the syntax.  Oh, just saw the accept. :)

Comment: ok there is still a problem ^^
my sql script stops right after the trigger was created.
why? because of the END?
i have to create much more tables with auto incrementing ids than i postet above. (321 in the whole, wo i have to define a trigger for each table, but it stops after the first trigger)

Comment: and theres again something -.-
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
i opened and closed everything correctly -.-