# Oracle SQL auto increment PLS-00103

Tags: sql, oracle

When I run this SQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER test_trigger
BEFORE INSERT
ON FITNESS_BMR
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SELECT t1_seq.nextval INTO :NEW.ID FROM dual;
END;
```

I get this error:

```
"Error at line 7: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ""CREATE""",""
```

Does anybody know why?

Comment: Is this in a script, with another statement immediately before it (possibly a `create table` or `create sequence` from your previous question), and that statement doesn't end with a semi-colon; or if it is a block, a `/`? Something before or after the snippet you've shown appears to be causing or experiencing the problem I think, so if there is more code please show that too.

Comment: You should check out SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/about.html.  It is really fun and a good way to learn about SQL, solve problems, and share Schemas/SELECTs with others.  :)

Comment: Th commands in [Michael Durant's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15957306/266304) to your previous question work exactly as shown as long as you have a `/` after the `create trigger`, when run in SQL*Plus or SQL Developer. So you're either doing something different, missing the `/`, or in a different client that doesn't like having the commands together. You need to show exactly what you're running and give more info about where you're running it.

Answer (score 0):

I used your code in **[an SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7aa83)** and I got a slightly different error:

`ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement`

I changed your code to just remove the semicolon after `dual` and I could create with no error.  Also the table must exist, but I assume for you it already does!  ;)

```
create table FITNESS_BMR ( a number(2) );

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER test_trigger
BEFORE INSERT
ON FITNESS_BMR
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SELECT t1_seq.nextval INTO :NEW.ID FROM dual
END;
```

Comment: I don't believe SQL Fiddle supports PL/SQL blocks... and I'm not entirely sure if the trigger block needs to be placed in the "schema" section;

Comment: All DDL has to be in the schema section of SQL Fiddle, but it seems to be picky with triggers. The semi-colon is definitely required after `dual` though. You aren't seeing an error without it because it isn't attempting to execute it - you need a `/` on a new line after the `end;`; but then it goes back to ORA-00900, despite the statement now being valid in SQL*Plus etc., so that seems to be a Fiddle glitch.

Comment: I've had this problem before... now remembered a workaround, putting the final `end;` on the previous line (no idea why!). New [SQL Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/03553/2)

Comment: @AlexPoole: Nice fiddle.  Put that as a full answer.  I think you got it.

Comment: Oh and @Sathya, I think SQL Fiddle does support anything an oracle database would support.  If you read their about page, it says they actually create a database using your fiddle in their back end. **http://sqlfiddle.com/about.html**

Comment: The code is exactly what Michael Durant posted in a previous answer, apart from the trailing `/`, and the workaround to the SQL Fiddle glitch. I still have no idea what the OP is doing differently/wrong, but that fiddle doesn't really add anything new.